# How can I prove exercise 89, section 5.5 from Stewart, Calculus - Early transcendentals (7th ed)

Tags: integration

For $a$ and $b$ positive,  prove that:
$$\int_0^1 x^a(1-x)^b dx = \int_0^1 x^b(1-x)^a dx $$

I've tried:
$$
u = 1-x, du = -dx
$$

$$
x = 1 - u
$$

$$
\int_1^0 (1-u)^au^b (-du) = \int_0^1 u^b (1-u)^a du
$$

Now I can't think. What should I do? I have no idea.

Comment: Move that minus sign out front and you're done!

Comment: There are multiple versions of Stewart's book (single variable/combined/early transcendentals/etc). Please learn to provide citations correctly, and provide a useful citation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, my apologies. I added citations.

Comment: I think you've already done everything.

Answer (score 4):

You have actually finished the proof.
Note that in $\int_0^1 u^b (1-u)^a du$, $u$ is just a dummy variable, so we can replace it by any other variable. Hence,
$$\int_0^1 x^a(1-x)^b dx = \int_0^1 u^b (1-u)^a du = \int_0^1 x^b (1-x)^a dx.$$

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had to manipulate u and x again. Because u = 1 - x, I was replacing 1 - x.